# why does Make give error while compiling?

Tags: makefile

```
    make[2]: Entering directory '/media/admin/86335594-e867-44ba-8523-10e2454c2182/admin/Downloads/vr400v3_GPL/apps/public/libusb-1.0.18/libusb'
    make[3]: Entering directory '/media/admin/86335594-e867-44ba-8523-10e2454c2182/admin/Downloads/vr400v3_GPL/apps/public/libusb-1.0.18/libusb'
     /bin/mkdir -p '/home/mobile/vr400v3_GPL/build/../apps/public/libusb-1.0.18/install/lib'
     /bin/sh ../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c   libusb-1.0.la '/home/mobile/vr400v3_GPL/build/../apps/public/libusb-1.0.18/install/lib'
    ../libtool: 3212: install_prog+=/usr/bin/install: not found
    ../libtool: 3270: install_prog+= -c: not found
    ../libtool: 3274: install_shared_prog+= -c: not found
    ../libtool: 3232: files+= libusb-1.0.la: not found
    libtool: install: you must specify an install program
    libtool: install: Try `libtool --help --mode=install' for more information.
    make[3]: *** [Makefile:374: install-libLTLIBRARIES] Error 1
    make[3]: Leaving directory '/media/admin/86335594-e867-44ba-8523-10e2454c2182/admin/Downloads/vr400v3_GPL/apps/public/libusb-1.0.18/libusb'
    make[2]: *** [Makefile:747: install-am] Error 2
    make[2]: Leaving directory '/media/admin/86335594-e867-44ba-8523-10e2454c2182/admin/Downloads/vr400v3_GPL/apps/public/libusb-1.0.18/libusb'
    make[1]: *** [Makefile:398: install-recursive] Error 1
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/media/admin/86335594-e867-44ba-8523-10e2454c2182/admin/Downloads/vr400v3_GPL/apps/public/libusb-1.0.18'
```

Any idea how to fix it ~? Ubuntu 22.04 Trying to make https://www.tp-link.com/au/support/download/archer-vr400/#GPL-Code

Not sure whats the issue// I copied install to this folder but didnt work and also libusb-1.0.la

Comment: What does `libtool --help --mode=install` give you?

Comment: Please edit your question and fix the formatting.  It's hardly readable as-is.

Comment: libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libusb-1.0.so.0.1.0 /home/mobile/vr400v3_GPL/build/../apps/public/libusb-1.0.18/install/lib/libusb-1.0.so.0.1.0
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat '.libs/libusb-1.0.so.0.1.0': No such file or directory.Not sure where this libs folder is ..I installed libusb using apt